# Conflito de onFling com onSingleTapUp em GestureDetector

Tags: android, gridview

Tenho uma aplicação a correr em Android com uma GridView (grelha).

Nessa grelha eu preciso de detetar vários eventos e por isso estou a usar um detetor de gestos. Só que ao clicar num item da grelha, por vezes é acionado o evento de `onFling` em vez de `onSingleTapUp`.

O comportamento é mesmo assim ou estarei a fazer alguma coisa errada? Se é mesmo assim o que posso fazer para contornar o problema?

```
class DetectorGestosGrelha extends SimpleOnGestureListener 
{
        /**
         * Para passar de uma grelha para outra ao deslizar o dedo
         * da direita para a esquerda.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, 
                              float velocityX,float velocityY) 
        {
            //meu código
            return false;    
        }

        /**
         * Para ir para outra atividade ao clicar num elemento da grelha.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) 
        {
            //meu código
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) 
        {
            //meu código
            super.onLongPress(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                               float distanceX, float distanceY) 
        {
            //meu código
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) 
        {
            super.onShowPress(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) 
        {
            //meu código
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: *Cross-posting* : [GestureDetector conflit onFling vs onSingleTapUp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416183/gesturedetector-conflit-onfling-vs-onsingletapup)

Comment: Estás a aplicar algum "filtro" para aceitar a "gesture" como "Fling"? Ou seja, só deves aceitar uma "gesture" como "Fling" se esta tiver uma determinada amplitude e velocidade.

Comment: @ramaral estou mas é dentro do `onFling`.

Comment: Sim seria aí. Tenta aumentar os valores.

Comment: @ramaral isso já está direito, não me expliquei bem então. Vai parar ao `onFling` mas não faz nada, mas  depois não passa no `onSingleTapUp` e não faz o que eu quero que é ir para outra atividade.

Comment: A sugestão seguinte seria o método retornar `false`, mas isso já tu fazes. Não me ocorre mais nada.

Comment: A dificuldade está em o problema não ocorrer sempre, no entanto experimenta colocar `return false` no método `onDown()`.

Comment: Vê a classe **GestureEventLogger.java** desta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98209/2541) e coloca os teus *return* iguais.

Comment: O problema parece ser a sensibilidade ao toque, se eu colocar o tablet deitado e usar uma caneta própria dá certo, mas como é um software para um restaurante tem de ser rápido e por isso é que dá esse problema.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40613/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-ramaral).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema com uma espécie de gambiarra:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, 
                       float velocityX,float velocityY) {

    int pos  = pointToPosition((int) e1.getX(), (int) e1.getY());

    int pos2 = pointToPosition((int) e2.getX(), (int) e2.getY());

    if( pos == pos2 ) { 
         //executa o código do click
    }
    else {
         //age com o onFling normal.
    }
    return true;    
}
```

Ou seja, se a posição do `onFling` inicial for igual à final, mesmo objeto, então é um click, senão faz as "deslizamentos" normais.

Comment: Não deveria ser necessário fazer isso! Ou seja, se as duas posições são iguais, o `onFling()` não deveria ser chamado.

Comment: @ramaral mas a verdade é que são. Só se me escapou alguma coisa...